# Redirecting to URL with firebase functions - google cloud functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I have a trigger function in firebase to perform simple actions when the user registers. I'm trying to redirect the user to create their profile when they sign up. But I can't find a way to do it with firebase trigger functions. Here is my function.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);



exports.userJoined = functions.auth.user().onCreate(user => {


        const newUser = user.uid;
        console.log(newUser)
        const notification = {
            displayName: '',
            displayImage: 'https://wattleparkkgn.sa.edu.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/placeholder-profile-sq.jpg',
            location: '',
            phoneNumber: '',
        }
        const createNotification = (notification => {
            return admin.firestore().collection('Accounts').doc(newUser).set(notification).then(

REDIRECT USER TO ANOTHER PAGE



                )
        })
        return createNotification(notification)




})
```

I need to add to it something that would redirect the user to another page.

Comment: you need to orchestrate your application in a different way since you are using a background function, there is not a way to trigger your client based on this, you could set a listener to the Accounts collection if you have the uid available on the client when you craete your user.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a boolean:

```
  const notification = {
            displayName: '',
            displayImage: 'https://wattleparkkgn.sa.edu.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/placeholder-profile-sq.jpg',
            location: '',
            phoneNumber: '',
            registered : true,
        }
```

Then in the client side, retrieve the data and check if `registered` is equal to `true` and redirect the user. Though, it is better to just redirect the user in the client side without needing the trigger function. The `onCreate` function will get triggered everytime a new user registers to the application. So in the client side, if you have a button that is clicked that will enable the user to register, then you can just redirect in the client side.

In the client side, to redirect just check if `user.uid` is null or not.

Comment: thats the thing, I don't have a register function. Its phone authentication. (same form for sign up and sign in) I'll try your solution though.